How to authenticate PACGA ARM instruction
Below are two ARM links about the PACGA instruction. I cannot find anywhere information about how to authenticate the returned PACGA code. What instruction is used for authenticating PACGA??? For PACIA, authentication is done with AUTIA. For PACIB, authentication is done with AUTIB. But I cannot find a description of AUTGA anywhere.
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/fbm1476202745161
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2024-03/Base-Instructions/PACGA--Pointer-Authentication-Code--using-Generic-key-
I have looked all over the internet and ARM resources and cannot find anything.
EDIT: It looks like you just re-generate the PACGA and compare it to the previous generation

It looks like PACGA is for generic authentication of arbitrary data, not actually related to pointers. So you authenticate by doing PACGA again and seeing if you get the same result.
